# Change size and position of objects programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to change size and position of some objects in viewDidLayoutSubviews(). Method fixPositions() is called, but all changes apply only after I go to the next screen.

Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    let width = filterMainView.frame.width / 5

    filterView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, 50.0)

    fixPositions(filterSubview, image: filterImage, button: filterButton, width: width)
}

func fixPositions(mainView: UIView, image: UIImageView, button: UIButton, width: CGFloat) {
    let buttonFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, 50.0)

    button.frame = buttonFrame
    mainView.frame = buttonFrame
    image.frame = CGRectMake((width - 30.0)/2, 10.0, 30.0, 30.0)
}
```

Besides, filterView works fine, it is changed immediately. What can be wrong with this method?

Comment: Try to put your code in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`

Comment: @AnthonyRoani But what if I should accomplish those actions 5 times? It will add many extra code lines.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using these delegate methods. Why don't you call `self.layoutIfNeeded()` after that your element frame has been changed ? This will update the frame. I think you shouldn't use `layoutSubviews()` methods for your case (as you UIButton frame seems to changed all the time)

Comment: @AnthonyRoani Yes! Finally it works! Thanks!

Comment: Cool :-)) ! So I will write my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `self.layoutIfNeeded()` after that your element frame has been changed will update the frame. It's better to use it when the frame is always changing.

Answer (score 0):

This logic should be in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`

`viewdidLayoutSubviews` is called after the layout is done. Putting layout logic there can be bad because you can potentially get into an endless layout and relayout loop.

Comment: But I should call this function 5 times. It will make my code longer. Furthermore, some methods which I call from `viewdidLayoutSubviews` are working fine. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Had for me to say without seeing more of the code. Layout logic should happen in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` so it is possible that you are experiencing some weirdness by handling it `viewDidLayoutSubviews`